# python3 bit shift more than 64 times

Tags: python-3.x, mapping, bit-manipulation, long-integer

I have a trouble to make a function that may shift a bit more than 64 sites.

I'm making an mapping and inverse mapping function on an array `table`. I fill the `table` with numbers having only two 1 bits in ascending order. The mapping function `map(number)` returns the positions of two bits in `table[number]`. Inverse mapping function `imap(k,l)` works as it make a number with two bits at `k` and `l` site. And it returns the index where the number is in the `table`.

For example, I generate `table` as

```
idx number(binary)
0       11
1       101
2       110
3       1001
...      ...
```

If I use `map(3)`, it will return `(3,0)`
If I use `imap(3,0)`, it will return `3`

**Here is the problem:**
If I use `imap(63,0)`, it fails to find the corresponding number in `table` even though `table` contains the number. My code looks like

```
def imap(k,l):
        code=(1<<k)^(1<<l)
        from bisect import bisect_left
        idx=bisect_left(table,code) 
        if idx!=len(table) and table[idx]==code:
                return idx
        raise valueError
```

And I've found that `code=(1<<k)^(1<<l)` part throws `-111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` in my code.
I test `(1<<63)^(1<<0)` in python3 idle, it return

```
>>> format((1<<63)^(1<<0),'b')
'1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
```

**Why they show different result?**

Comment: Can't reproduce. When I add a `print(format(code, "b"))` line to your function it prints the correct value, not the negative one.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for checking. Now I realize that if I use `k,l` from a numpy array, then it throw negative value. Then I should look for method to convert a number from numpy array to a python-int number

Comment: So you have found the solution?

Comment: @DanielHao in my `imap` code, `code=(1<<int(k))^(1<<int(l))` solves the problem